# What happens when I assign a temporary int to a const reference in C++?

Tags: c++, function, reference, return, temporary-objects

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Does a const reference class member prolong the life of a temporary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784262/does-a-const-reference-prolong-the-life-of-a-temporary)

let say that I have a function  `f`:

```
int f(int x){return x;}

const int &a=f(1);
```

I know that `f(1)` is just a temporary and i will be destroyed after this statement, but

1. does making the reference const will give f(1) a long life ?
2. if yes, where `f(1)` is gonna be stored ?
3. and is that mean that `x` also did not get destroyed when it run out of scope?
4. what is the difference between `f(1)` and `x`?

Comment: You need a good C++ book.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: @Ben Few (even good) books cover this.

Comment: @Konrad: Maybe he was referring to the last question...

Comment: @NiklasB. I’m not sure I would get all the differences right. Still sounds like a good non-beginner question.

Comment: @KonradRudolph what I dont understand is how f(1) return the value, since it's an expression then it gonna return a value to f(1), so is that mean that it will act like creating a new variable int called f(1) like this : int f(1)=1;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're confusing expressions with values.

1) The lifetime of the temporary value returned by the expression `f(1)` will have its lifetime extended.  This rule is unique for `const` references.

2) Anywhere the compiler wants, but probably on the stack.

3) Maybe.  It depends on whether the compiler copied `x` or performed copy elision.  Since the type is `int`, it doesn't matter.

4) Lots of differences.  One is the name of a local variable inside `int f(int)`.  It is an lvalue.  The other is an expression which calls `int f(int)` and evaluates to an rvalue.

Comment: :I know that expressions return value, but how this values are stored in f(1), does the compiler simply assign f(1) to 1 like this : int f(1)=1; or something else ?

Answer (score 3):

Binding a temporary to a `const&` extends the lifetime of the temporary to the lifetime of the reference.

Comment: if it extends the lifetime of the temporary, then where f(1) is get stored and does it have it's own address and can be changed like normal variable  ?

Comment: @AbdessamadBond Whether it can be changed like a normal variable is (I think) an open question; you'd need a `const_cast` to be able to change it, and even then, the results might be undefined behavior.  (I think the intent was that they be undefined behavior, but I'm far from sure that wording requiring this actually appears in the standard.)

Comment: @JamesKanze The only case where UB can be caused by a `const_cast` is if the object has been declared `const`. As far as I can see, this is never the case for a temporary.

Comment: @pmr That's the usual case (and an rvalue of non-class type isn't cv-qualified).  I know that there was intent at one point to extend this rule to temporaries bound to references; I don't know what became of that intent.  (The issue comes up if you have a `void f(int const&)`, and you call it with `f(3)`.  Is the compiler required to create a new temporary each time?  Or can it assume that the temporary `3` hasn't changed?)