# c++ why const& can get const values?

Tags: c++

I understand why `int& x=1` is illegal(you can't have reference to constant value), but I don't understand why `const int& x=1` is legal? How can you have reference to the number "1"? It is not even a defined variable.

EDIT: I read the answer given in this post: [What happens when I assign a temporary int to a const reference in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9585535/what-happens-when-i-assign-a-temporary-int-to-a-const-reference-in-c) but can someone explain what does he means "The lifetime of the temporary value returned by the expression f(1) will have its lifetime extended. This rule is unique for const references."? so literals are stored as int on the stack or not? Thanks!

Comment: I think it's an effect of const references extending temporaries' lifetime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> (you can't have reference to constant value)

You almost got it.

You cannot have a **non-constant** reference to a constant value.

You can have a **constant** reference to a constant value. (Which extends the lifetime of said value to the lifetime of that reference).

Comment: The missing step in your answer is how a literal `1` turns into a value you can refer to. Which was the actual question.

Comment: @Quentin Ah well, I think it's a duplicate then alright.

Answer (score 1):

The second case with const reference is allowed, because then a temporary object of type `int` is created, and the reference refers to this temporary object.

Answer (score 0):

This is a C++ language feature. [Click here](http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/) for an easy explanation.

**EDIT**

From the link:

> Normally, a temporary object lasts only until the end of the full
>   expression in which it appears. However, C++ deliberately specifies
>   that binding a temporary object to a reference to const on the stack
>   lengthens the lifetime of the temporary to the lifetime of the
>   reference itself, and thus avoids what would otherwise be a common
>   dangling-reference error

Answer (score 0):

In this case you have the constant reference to a constant value, which under the hood means creating a temp variable whole life time is bound to the life time of the reference.

Comment: By default literals are not stored anywhere, so the second part of your answer is wrong.

Comment: A literal in this case is a temp variable, which lifetime is bound to the lifetime of the reference. I will clarify this in the answer.

Comment: And that's the actual answer to OP ;)

Answer (score -1):

Because C++ says so. The language is defined this way. The language creators decided to allow it.