# C++ return a class into a const reference or not?

Tags: c++

Assume there is a method which returns a `std::set`:

```
std::set<string> MyClass::myMethod() const
{
   std::set<string> result;
   // ... some code to fill result ...
   return result;
}
```

In the caller side we can store result of `myMethod` in two ways:

```
void MyClass::test()
{
const std::set<string>  s1 = myMethod();  // 1
const std::set<string>& s2 = myMethod();  // 2 (using reference)
// ... some code to use s1 or s2 ...
}
```

My questions are:

- Is there any difference between them?
- Which way is better and
  efficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theoretically, the second version is better because it doesn't require the extra copy.

In practice, RVO will likely kick in so they should be about the same.

Comment: Does the first version require the copy (RVO aside) if the type has a move constructor and/or a move assignment operator?

Comment: In practice you prefer which way?

Comment: Theoretically, both versions may require an extra copy.  In practice, neither will.  Using the reference is just obfuscation.

Answer (score 4):

```
const std::set<string>  s1 = myMethod();  // 1
```

The return of `myMethod` is copied into s1. Depending on the size, this could take a long time.

```
const std::set<string>& s2 = myMethod();  // 2 (using reference)
```

A reference to the temporary returned by `myMethod` is stored. This incurs one less copy than the above method, so it is a little faster (assuming no optimizations).

This is a [special case feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784262/does-a-const-reference-prolong-the-life-of-a-temporary) that is used to make a reference to a variable that  would otherwise cease to exist at that `;`. This works ONLY if it is a `const&`, which in your example it is, or an Rvalue reference - `&&` (thanks @Kos).

Comment: Not only `const&`, this applies to `&&` too.

Comment: @Kos That is a Rvalue reference isnt it.. Im afraid i havent updated myself on move semantics and the related changes yet.. please feel free to edit and add details.

Comment: In C++03, the reference will be (or can be) initialized to refer to a copy, and not to the returned object.  Formally, there is no difference between the two.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, these are different:

1. `const std::set<string>  s1 = myMethod();  // 1` : copy the temporary object
2. `const std::set<string>& s2 = myMethod();  // 2 (using reference)` : the lifetime of the temporary is lengthened, it avoid one copy

See the [Guru of the week #88](http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/). Note that a compiler can optimize this by making it the same efficiency-wise.

Comment: Note that a compiler can "pessimize" the initialization of the reference to use a copy.

Answer (score 2):

There is unlikely to be any difference in practice. I've tested the following with `g++ 4.7.2`:

```
#include <string>

extern std::string f();
extern void g(const std::string&, const std::string&);

int main() {
  std::string        x = f();
  const std::string& y = f();
  g(x, y);
}
```

And it produces identical code for both calls to `f()`:

```
LEHB0:
        call    __Z1fv
LEHE0:
        leaq    16(%rsp), %rdi
LEHB1:
        call    __Z1fv
LEHE1:
        leaq    16(%rsp), %rsi
```

Comment: +1 Nice test, And how about portability? Can we trust all C++ compilers to have same output?

Comment: @MasoudM.: We clearly can't expect *all* compilers to behave in any particular way. However, I'd expect any good compiler to perform this optimization.

Comment: Which way is better and you usually choose?

Comment: I'd use the simpler version (i.e. by value) until and unless this shows up during profiling.

Answer (score 1):

1. The first version will create the `std::set` object, and it will be moved in this line

   `const std::set<string>  s1 = myMethod();`
2. This will extend the lifetime of the `std::set` object created in the method :

   `const std::set<string>& s2 = myMethod();`

Therefore, performance-wise both are doing the same.