# Correct way to return an rvalue reference to this

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, rvalue

The code below results in **Undefined Behaviour**. Be sure to read ALL the answers for completeness.

---

When chaining an object via the `operator<<` I want to preserve the lvalue-ness / rvalue-ness of the object:

```
class Avenger {
  public:
    Avenger& operator<<(int) & {
      return *this;
    }
    Avenger&& operator<<(int) && {
      return *this; // compiler error cannot bind lvalue to rvalue
      return std::move(*this);
    }
};
void doJustice(const Avenger &) {};
void doJustice(Avenger &&) {};

int main() {
  Avenger a;
  doJustice(a << 24); // parameter should be Avenger&
  doJustice(Avenger{} << 24); // parameter should be Avenger&&

  return 0;
}
```

I cannot simply return `*this` which implies that the type of `*this` of an `rvalue` object is still an `lvalue reference`. I would have expected to be an `rvalue reference`.

- Is it correct / recommended to return `std::move(*this)` on an member overloaded for the `&&` qualifier, or should other method be used? I know that `std::move` is just a cast, so I think it’s ok, I just want to double check.
- What is the reason/explanation that `*this` of an `rvalue` is an `lvalue reference` and not an `rvalue reference`?
- I remember seeing in C++14 something about move semantics of `*this`. Is that related to this? Will any of the above change in C++14?

Comment: "lvalue" and "rvalue" are *value categories*. Value category is a property of expressions - not of objects. There is thus no such thing as an "rvalue object" or an "lvalue object."

Comment: Nor is there any such thing as a pointer-to-rvalue. A dereferenced pointer to an object type is always an lvalue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is **NOT ok** to return `std::move(*this)` on a member overloaded for the `&&` qualifier. The problem here is not with the `std::move(*this)` (which other answers correctly show that it is ok)  but with the return type. The problem is very subtle and it was almost done by the c++11 standardization committee. It is explained by **Stephan T. Lavavej** in his presentation [Don’t Help the Compiler](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Don-t-Help-the-Compiler) during `Going Native 2013`. His example can be found at around minute 42 in the linked video. His example is slightly different and doesn’t involve `*this` and uses overload by parameter reference type rather than by method ref qualifiers but the principle is still the same.

So what is wrong with the code?

Short introduction: a reference bound to a temporary object prolongs the lifetime of the temporary object for the lifetime of the reference. That is what makes code like this be ok:

```
void foo(std::string const & s) {
  //
}

foo("Temporary std::string object constructed from this char * C-string");
```

The important part here is that this property is not transitive, meaning that for the reference to prolong the lifetime of the temporary object, it must bind **directly** to the temporary object, and not to a reference to it.

Returning to my example:

For completness let’s add a function that takes only a const lvalue reference to `Avenger` (no rvalue reference overload):

```
void doInjustice(Avenger const &) {};
```

the next two calls result in UB if referencing the parameter inside the functions:

```
doInjustice(Avenger{} << 24); // calls `void doInustice(Avenger const &) {};`
doJustice(Avenger{} << 24); // calls `void doJustice(Avenger &&) {};`
```

The temporary objects constructed at parameter evaluation are destroyed as soon as the function are called for the reasons exposed above and the parameters are dangling references. Referencing them inside the functions will result in UB.

---

The **correct** way is to return by value:

```
class Avenger {
  public:
    Avenger& operator<<(int) & {
      return *this;
    }
    Avenger operator<<(int) && {
      return std::move(*this);
    }
};
```

A copy is still eluded with the move semantics, and the return is a temporary, meaning that it will call the correct overload, but we avoid this subtle but nasty silent bug.

---

The example of `Stephan T. Lavavej`: [Don’t Help the Compiler](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Don-t-Help-the-Compiler) (42m–45m)

```
string&& join(string&& rv, const char * ptr) {
  return move(rv.append(", ").append(ptr));
}
string meow() { return "meow"; }

const string& r = join(meow(), "purr");
// r refers to a destroyed temporary!

//Fix:
string join(string&& rv, const char * ptr) {
  return move(rv.append(", ").append(ptr));
}
```

Posts on SO explaining the prolonging of life of temporary objects through references:

- [Does a const reference prolong the life of a temporary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784262/does-a-const-reference-prolong-the-life-of-a-temporary)
- [Initializing a reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21045518/initializing-a-reference)

Comment: You are not going to dangle unless you do:
`Avenger&& dangle = Avenger{} << 24;`
If all of your use cases look more like:
`doJustice(Avenger{} << 24);`
then you are fine.

Comment: @HowardHinnant from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784262/does-a-const-reference-prolong-the-life-of-a-temporary I understand that `A temporary bound to a reference parameter in a function call persists until the completion of the full expression containing the call.` (standard quote). In `doJustice(Avenger{}.operator<<(24));` the way I see it (I could be wrong) the temporary is **not** bound to the reference parameter of `doJustice`. The result of `operator<<` is bound to the reference parameter of `doJustice`. Could you explain why this case doesn't result in a dangling reference?

Comment: A [full expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214153/lifetime-of-temporaries) is not a sub-expression.  The full expression in this case "ends" at the `;` (and this is usually the case).  So `doJustice(Avenger{}.operator<<(24))` has a sub-expression `Avenger{}.operator<<(24)`.  The temporary `Avenger{}` is passed to `operator<<`, and it lasts until the end of the enclosing **full expression** `doJustice(Avenger{}.operator<<(24));`.  Nothing in the OP is UB: it is adjacent to UB, and it is a bad practice to return a `&&` outside of a cast, but this posts details are in error.

Answer (score 11):

The type of `this` depends on the cv-qualifier of the member function: `Avenger*` or `const Avenger*`

But not on its *ref-qualifier*. The *ref-qualifier* is used only to determine the function to be called.

Thus, the type of `*this` is `Avenger&` or `const Avenger&`, no matter if you use the `&&` or not. The difference is that the overload with `&&` will be used then the called object is a r-value, while the `&` will not.

Note that rvalue-ness is a property of the expression, not the object. For example:

```
void foo(Avenger &x)
{
    foo(x); //recursive call
}
void foo(Avenger &&x)
{
    foo(x); //calls foo(Avenger &)!
}
```

That is, although in the second `foo()`, `x` is defined as an r-value reference, any use of the expression `x` is still an l-value. The same is true for `*this`.

So, if you want to move out the object, `return std::move(*this)` is The Right Way.

Could things have been different had `this` been defined as a reference value instead of as a pointer? I'm not sure, but I think that considering `*this` as an r-value could lead to some insane situations...

I didn't hear of anything changing about this in C++14, but I may be mistaken...

Comment: Even if `this` had been defined as a reference, it wouldn't have made a difference. `int &&f(int &&x) { return x; }` is invalid, because inside `f`, `x` is an lvalue.

Comment: The result of dereferencing a pointer is always an lvalue. This isn't going to change, nor does there seem to be a sensible way to change this.

Answer (score 7):

`std::move` is perhaps better called `rvalue_cast`.

But it is not called that.  Despite its name, it is nothing but an rvalue cast: `std::move` does not move.

All named values are lvalues, as are all pointer dereferences, so using `std::move` or `std::forward` (aka conditional rvalue cast) to turn a named value that is an rvalue reference at point of declaration (or other reasons) into an rvalue at a particular point is kosher.

Note, however, that you rarely want to return an rvalue reference.  If your type is cheap to move, you usually want to return a literal.  Doing so uses the same `std::move` in the method body, but now it actually triggers moving into the return value.  And now if you capture the return value in a reference (say `auto&& foo = expression;`), reference lifetime extension works properly.  About the only good time to return an rvalue reference is in an rvalue cast: which sort of makes the fact that `move` is an rvalue cast somewhat academic.

Comment: <<But it is not called that. Despite its name, it is nothing but an rvalue cast: `std::move` does not move.>> I don't know if I agree with this phrase 100%. After all, if you `std::move(x)`, shouldn't you consider that `x` is invalid after that? That is, that effectively the _value_ that lived on `x` went on (_moved on_) to live somewhere else?

Comment: @massa As a general rule, it is rare to have a reason to cast a value to an rvalue without having the value transfer to another location, yes, but there are a handful of exceptions.

Comment: @bolov cautionary note added

Comment: I see myself using `x = std::move(y)` a lot of times instead of the equivalent `x.swap(y)` or `std::swap(x, y)` (assuming `y` is going out of scope soon) because it is really much more informative...

Comment: @massa yes, and that does an rvalue assign, which does move `y`'s state.  The `move`, however, did nothing to `y`'s state: the operation after the cast did.

Answer (score 4):

This answer is in response to [bolov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2805305/bolov)'s comment to me under his answer to his question.

```
#include <iostream>

class Avenger
{
    bool constructed_ = true;

  public:
    Avenger() = default;

    ~Avenger()
    {
        constructed_ = false;
    }

    Avenger(Avenger const&) = default;
    Avenger& operator=(Avenger const&) = default;
    Avenger(Avenger&&) = default;
    Avenger& operator=(Avenger&&) = default;

    Avenger& operator<<(int) &
    {
      return *this;
    }

    Avenger&& operator<<(int) &&
    {
      return std::move(*this);
    }

    bool alive() const {return constructed_;}
};

void
doJustice(const Avenger& a)
{
    std::cout << "doJustice(const Avenger& a): " << a.alive() << '\n';
};

void
doJustice(Avenger&& a)
{
    std::cout << "doJustice(Avenger&& a): " << a.alive() << '\n';
};

int main()
{
  Avenger a;
  doJustice(a << 24); // parameter should be Avenger&
  doJustice(Avenger{} << 24); // <--- this one
  // Avenger&& dangling = Avenger{} << 24;
  // doJustice(std::move(dangling));
}
```

This will portably output:

```
doJustice(const Avenger& a): 1
doJustice(Avenger&& a): 1
```

What the above output demonstrates is that a temporary `Avenger` object will not be destructed until the sequence point demarcated by the ';' just before the comment "// <--- this one" above.

I've removed all undefined behavior from this program.  This is a fully conforming and portable program.

Comment: since compiler is free to do anything if it detects UB, I am not convinced that your example is a proof. I compiled your code with some variations and I got some strange behaviours. I am not trying to hold to my idea, but is it possible you could show what the standard says. Nevertheless if what you say is true I am interested to know the reason why that is not UB.

Comment: should I post a separate question on SO specifically about this?

Comment: -1: "portable on non-optimized builds" is exceedingly unlikely.  Trashing data that has been destroyed is a pretty standard thing to do in debug builds, and the call to `doJustice` should use the same stack area that `dangling`'s temporary was stored in.

Comment: You guys completely missed my point.  I've removed all U.B. from the example code.

Comment: @bolov I think "correct time to return r-ref to this" and "correct way to return r-ref to this" are close enough to put both in the same Q&A. Howard, have an upvote. Both points of view are valid as far as I can tell; returning the reference will be only slightly faster and returning the value will be only slightly safer. Indeed the only danger comes from a persistent r-ref, which may well occur from uniform, idiomatic use of `auto &&`.

Answer (score 1):

My git copy of the C++ Standard (page 290, section15.2, point 6) says:

> "The exceptions to this lifetime rule [of a reference binding to a
>   temporary extending the lifetime of that temporary] are:
>
> sub 9 - A temporary object bound to a reference parameter in a
>              function call persists until the completion of the
>              full-expression containing the call.
>
> sub 10 - The lifetime of a temporary bound to the returned value
>              in a function return statement (9.6.3) is not extended;
>              the temporary is destroyed at the end of the
>              full-expression in the return statement.  [...]"

Therefore, the implicit this `parameter' passed to

```
Avenger&& operator<<(int) &&
{
      return std::move(*this);
}
```

ends its life at the ; of the statement that calls operator<< on a temporary object, **even** if a reference is bound to it. So this fails:

```
Avenger &&dangler = Avenger{} << 24; // destructor already called
dangler << 1; // Operator called on dangling reference
```

If OTOH the return is by value:

```
Avenger operator<<(int) &&
{
      return std::move(*this);
}
```

then none of that misery happens, and there is often no extra cost in terms of copying. And indeed, if you don't offer the compiler to create that return value by move-constructing from *this, then it 'll make a copy.
So snatch *this from the brink of oblivion, and have the best of both worlds.