# C++ compiler can silently accept wrong conversion and introduce unpredictable errors

Tags: c++, type-conversion, explicit

I have this simple code:

```
class A {
public:
    int m;
};

class B : public A {
public:
    B(const B& b) { /*...*/ }
    B(const A& a) { /*...*/ }
    int n;
};

const A& function()
{
    static A a;
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    const B& a = function();
    const int x = a.n; // !!!!! Error: probably reads some random mess

    /* ... */

    B b2 = function(); 

    /* ... */

    return 0;
}
```

In this code I demonstrate what can happen when you mistakenly write `const B& a = function()` instead of `const A& a = function()`. And the compiler does not catch this error! To catch this error at compile time, constructor `B(const A& a)` must be `explicit`. But marking constructor `explicit` disables ability to do `B b2 = function();` — it must be written uglier: `B b2(function());`

**Question:** Does there exist some way to catch this type of error at compile time while keeping the possibility to write this?

```
B b2 = function();
```

**EDIT:** As is stated by @ditskowitch and @n.m. - what i am supposing to be error is not error. For that, explicit contructor is not needed. It can teoreticaly be problem only if depending code expects that reference returned by function() points at some address as showed by @Rory Yorke

Comment: Let me better understand what you want. You wish `B& a = function()` to fail but `B b = function()` to succeed, right?

Comment: @n.m.: yes, you are right.

Comment: This is not likely to be possible.

Comment: I hope this isn't possible

Comment: @user1520427: please, explain why you hope?

Comment: @user3123061 I don't know, it just doesn't seem like something that would be inherently safe, I could be wrong though!

Answer (score 2):

The compiler behaves properly: since your `B class` has a constructor, accepting `const A&` - you actually commit that `B` can be properly instantiated from the instance of `A`. So there should not be any "random mess" in `x`, but the value, which the constructor assigns for `n`, when constructing from instance of `A`

Comment: But this is also bad. So, you say, compiler constructs temporary B. And then reference to this temporary is acessed later, but at this time that temporary B no longer exists!

Comment: @user3123061: this is not true. Lifetime of a temporary is extended in this case, see e.g. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784262/does-a-const-reference-prolong-the-life-of-a-temporary).

Comment: This is probably implementation specific, but see https://ideone.com/7ZI6OH for what might happen: &a in main() is not equal to &a in function().

Comment: @RoryYorke That's expected. `a` is bound to a *temporary*, not to the static variable from the function.

Answer (score 1):

> Question: Does there exist some way to catch this type of error at compile time while keeping the possibility to write this?

Marking your "B from A" constructor as `explicit`:

```
explicit B(const A& a) { /*...*/ }
```

will prevent the compiler from using it to perform an automatic conversion. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121162/what-does-the-explicit-keyword-in-c-mean) for more information.