# error: invalid initialization for struct in C++

Tags: c++, struct, compiler-errors, initialization, constants

Error:

> invalid initialization of reference of type `Assoc<float,
>   std::basic_string<char> >&` from expression of type `const
>   Assoc<float, std::basic_string<char> >`

for this code

```
Assoc<keyType,valueType>& found = internalStorage.get(find(key));//returns the value of some key
```

I'm sorry y'all, I know it's not interesting, but I'm perplexed.

Any ideas what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `internalStorage.get()` returns the object by value, and you're trying to bind a non-`const` reference to the returned temporary.

The best way to fix this depends on what it is exactly you're trying to do (and on the type of `internalStorage`):

- If you don't need to modify `found`, make the reference `const` (and see [Does a const reference prolong the life of a temporary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784262/does-a-const-reference-prolong-the-life-of-a-temporary)).
- If you do need to modify `found` (which is a copy of what's stored in `internalStorage`), simply remove the `&`.
- If you need to modify the object stored in `internalStorage`, you'll likely need to refactor the code.

Comment: Indeed. Make the reference const and it should work. Visual C++ unfortunately *does* allow this code :)