# C++ function returning string gives garbage in the text of the string

Tags: c++

So I have a function returning a `std::string` as follows:

```
string ReadShaderSource(const char* filename, GLint& shaderSize) // Load the shader source code.
{
    ifstream::pos_type size;
    string text;

    ifstream file(filename, ios::in | ios::binary | ios::ate);
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        size = file.tellg();
        shaderSize = (GLuint)size;

        text.resize(size);
        file.seekg(0, ios::beg);
        file.read(&text[0], text.size());
        file.close();

        return text;
    }
    else
    {
        SDL_ShowSimpleMessageBox(SDL_MESSAGEBOX_ERROR, "Fatal Error!",
            "Could not load the shader source code from the file.", NULL);
        Lunar::Exit();
    }

    return "";

}
```

But When I call the function like this:

```
const char* testStr = ReadShaderSource("test.glsl", size).c_str();
```

The value of testStr is full of this:

> 0x036fdcd8
>   "îþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþ...

Which makes no sense. The function returns the right value, so when I return text in the function it contains the source code of the shader, but when I do

```
const char* testStr = ReadShaderSource("test.glsl", size).c_str();
```

`testStr` is full of rubbish.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: thats because the scope of the returned string is limited to the lifetime of expression.  after line is complete, the return string is destroyed.  capture your return string as `const string &testStr = ..`

Comment: Is it possible `string text` is deleted from memory when the function exits?

Comment: Ok, makes I get it. How would I do it so that it is not destroyed?

Comment: Referring to std::string.cstr() is a dangling pointer if you do not store the resulting string of the function.

Comment: either copy the string or use const reference to extend its lifetime:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784262/does-a-const-reference-prolong-the-life-of-a-temporary

Comment: @Anycorn: using a reference for the result does not buy anything here.

Comment: It'd also be a good idea to check that `read` succeeded

Comment: @Alf, `std::string const &testStr = foo();` extends the lifetime of the returned temporary, if `foo()` returns `string` (but not if it returns `string&`)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf if you capture return value as a *local* const references the lifetime will be extended till the reference goes out of scope

Comment: @Anycom (and Matt), yes, and as I said, that does not buy anything here (rather it introduces needless complexity). well on the old usenet i would now follow up in these well-meaning explanations by noting that the `const` is not necessary with an rvalue reference, and launching into a tutorial on references and lifetime extension etc., including Bjarne's rationale, ARM vagueness,  Petru Marginean's original ScopeGuard, etc. etc., and there would be a back-and-forth exchange of useful opinions & insights, but Stack Overflow is not suited for that. old days gone. harumph.

Comment: @Alf I'm not sure what you're trying to say; OP's code is wrong, and the `std::string const &` suggestion makes the code correct. So this suggestion buys correctness at least.   **e:** I see now that you're making a roundabout reference (no pun intended) to the answer you have posted.. never mind

Comment: This bug is so common in C++ code that compilers should build in warnings for it. I've also seen it in Unicode libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use

```
string str = ReadShaderSource("test.glsl", size);
const char* testStr = str.c_str();
```

instead of

```
const char* testStr = ReadShaderSource("test.glsl", size).c_str();
```

When you use the second form, you are storing a pointer in `testStr` that is not valid any more since the returned value of the function is a temporary `string`.

As was pointed out by @IInspectable, you could also use a `const&` to extend the lifetime of the temporary object.

```
string const& str = ReadShaderSource("test.glsl", size);
const char* testStr = str.c_str();
```

The following program is well behaved:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string foo()
{
   return "This is a test.";
}

void bar(std::string const& str)
{
   std::cout << str.c_str() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
   std::string const& str = foo();
   bar(str);
   std::cout << str.c_str() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: This is not strictly the only solution. You could also extend the [lifetime](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime) of the temporary by binding it to a const lvalue reference.

Answer (score 2):

Re

> “when I do `const char* testStr = ReadShaderSource("test.glsl", size).c_str();` `testStr` is full of rubbish.”

you're initializing the pointer to point to a buffer in a temporary `string`, that has ceased to exist already when the initialization finishes.

Instead use a `string` for the result variable.

---

Note that the *conclusion* that the function returns garbage is unwarranted, it does not follow from that observation of garbage, but *might still be true*.

You should test anew, with proper result variable type, to check that.