# strange behaviors for boost::filesystem::path::string() output

Tags: c++, string, boost

There seem some strange behaviors for `pf.string()` output, where `pf` is generated with `p.filename()`, where `p` is of type `boost::filesystem::path` and constructed with *char const** or *std::string*.

Here is the code segment:

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  fs::path p(argv[0]);  // or fs::path p((std::string(argv[0])));
  fs::path &&pf = p.filename(); // or fs::path pf = p.filename();
  std::string const &name = p.filename().string();
  std::cout << "*" << name << "*\n";
  std::string const &p_name = pf.string();
  std::cout << "*" << p_name << "*\t";
  std::cout << "*" << name << "*\n";
  std::string s_name = p.filename().string();
  std::cout << "*" << s_name << "*\t";
  std::cout << "*" << name << "*\n";
  return 0;
}
```

The `argv[0]` here is `fs.out` and the output of the executable(compiled with `clang3.4`/ `gcc4.9` with `-O3`/`-O0`) is:

```
**
*fs.out*    **
*fs.out*    *fs.out*
```

The boost version I used is **1.55** from **Debian jessie(testing)** package.

My questions:

- Why `name` is empty in the first 2 lines?
- Why `p_name` is not empty but `name` is empty at Line 2?
- Why this program has the correct(?) output at Line 3 although it seems that there is no relationship between `s_name` and `name`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're taking references to temporaries.

Iff bound to a `const` reference (like `p_name`) the lifetime of the temporary will be extended to the end of the containing scope.

Otherwise you're simply invoking Undefined Behaviour. This also explains how `name` changes when you assign to a totally different variable. This apparently happens because `s_name` **happens** to allocate the same memory chunk that `name` still (*erronously*!) refers to. Much worse things might happen.

You should take the return values of `filename()` (and friends) by value (which should on modern compilers automatically behave as a *move* if the type supports that).

**Note** that MSVC does "appear" to accept this code and "do what you expect" - presumably because it has a non-standard extension that allows the lifetime of temporaries to be extended even when bound to non-const references.

Comment: Hmmmm... I am in doubt. Is `p_name` really valid because it's a const reference? Or does it "work" because he's working on `pf` instead of `p.filename()`? (I don't take references to temporaries, `const` or no, so I'd like to know about the fine print here.)

Comment: @DevSolar It does: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784262/does-a-const-reference-prolong-the-life-of-a-temporary (also: [GotW #88](http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/))

Comment: Thanks, I realize my mistake. I was thinking that as long as the return value is reference I can assign it to `const&`; but obviously I was wrong since `p.filename()` is destroyed.

Comment: BTW, should I always use `fs::path pf = p.filename();` instead of `fs::path &&pf = p.filename();` to rely compilers to do the optimization?

Comment: Compilers should do the move assignment if available (return-by-value is always treatable as _rvalue ref_)

Comment: @HongxuChen: Depending on the rest of your code, leaving such optimizations to the compiler might have the advantage of least confusion. Quite some C++ coders out there haven't quite caught up with C++11 yet, and if the compiler "does" C++11, you get the optimization implicitly. (I am doing three-platform portable code 9-to-5, and two out of three compilers involved still balk at C++11 code... :-( )

Comment: @DevSolar Thanks, I think can avoid `Object &&o = FunctionReturnByValue()` aggressively; I've seen a few talks saying that that's not good practice and rvalue reference had better be used in function argument passing(together with std::move) and when the performance is really important.

Comment: @DevSolar @sehe i just realized that there are still some benefits to use `Object&&o = FunctionReturnByValue()`. Here without `&&` the returned value is used as the argument of `Object`'s copy constructor, when NO `move constructor` for `Object` is provided.

Comment: @HongxuChen: Only if your compiler is too dumb for Return Value Optimization (RVO)...

Comment: @DevSolar You mean that `Object o` can still be constructed directly with the `return xxx` value inside `FunctionReturnByValue` for modern compilers and NOT a single `Object` is copied? I guess that may not be available if `Object` only has `Object(Object const&)` constructor?

Comment: @HongxuChen technically, this is copy-initialization, and it's been around since c++03 (perhaps c++89): http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization. In particular, read under `2)`: _"The last step is usually optimized out and the result of the conversion is constructed directly in the memory allocated for the target object, but the appropriate constructor (move or copy) is required to be accessible even though it's not used."_

Answer (score 3):

Nice one. ;-)

`name` is a **reference**. I.e., it only *refers* to `p.filename().string()`. That, however, is a *temporary*, i.e. it gets destroyed after the statement is done, leaving `name` to refer to invalid memory. You're in undefined behaviour country and are lucky your program didn't crash.

(sehe updated me on the fine print on `const &` with regards to your second question, so +1 to him.)

In the third round, `s_name` is an **object**, i.e. it holds a **copy** of `p.filename().string()` (and thus is valid). By some stroke of luck, the compiler apparently created that object in the same location that `name` refers to...

Needless to say, you should never *rely* on this kind of behaviour.

Comment: +1 I'd assert that he's **unlucky** that the program doesn't crash. Then again, with c++, one should **never** expect to get lucky.