# Unexpected behavior of reference to const temporary object

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

The following code compiles in Visual Studio 2013 without any warnings. Removing the comment in the last line will not compile. Is this a bug in Visual Studio 2013? If not, how am I supposed to understand it within the standard?

I think that allowing to take the reference of a temporary object is something very dangerous, isn't it?

```
struct A
{
    string a;

    void f( const string & toMove )
    {
        a = toMove;
    }
    void g( string & toMove )
    {
        a = toMove;
    }
} aa;

stringstream d_SS;
d_SS << "A string";
aa.f( d_SS.str() );
//aa.g( d_SS.str() );
```

---

Edit

In this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1565600/2549876), they explain that one is 'not allowed to get non-const reference to a temporary object'. My question would be then why we are allowed to get const references to temporary objects in the way `aa.f( d_SS.str() )` does. `d_SS.str()` is dead before it enters to the body of function!

Comment: I don't understand what the issue is that you're having here.  One takes a `const` reference, so passing a temporary to such function is perfectly ok since the function can't change the parameter anyway.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: In my understanding, being constant and being temporary are not the same thing and they do not imply each other. My comment to ravi's answer suggests that d_SS.str() is not constant since you can modify it.

Comment: Are you asking why `aa.f( d_SS.str() );` does not give an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> d_SS.str() is dead before it enters to the body of function!

Not true; it is still alive until the end of the current *full-expression* , which in this case is the semicolon at the end of `aa.f( d_SS.str() );` .

There is only danger if `aa.f` takes a reference or pointer to its argument and saves that to some external data area.  It's completely safe for `aa.f` to just read its argument.

Comment: Thank you. For reference, I found this other [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2784304/2549876). Just to be explicit: "allowing to take the reference of a temporary object is something very dangerous, isn't it?" is answered as: No, if it is a const reference because it will prolong the life of the object until the semicolon.