# Ternary operator and prolonging the lifetime of a temporary object via reference-to-const

Tags: c++, c++11, copy-constructor, temporary-objects

After seeing that [a local reference-to-const may prolong the life of a temporary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784262/does-a-const-reference-prolong-the-life-of-a-temporary), I encountered the need to conditionally bind a local reference-to-const to either a function parameter or the temporary result of a function call, i.e.:

```
class Gizmo
{
    // Rule of Five members implemented
};

Gizmo Frobnicate(const Gizmo& arg);

void ProcessGizmo(const Gizmo& arg, bool frobnicate)
{
    const Foo& local = frobnicate ? Frobnicate(arg) : arg;
    // Perform some work on local
}
```

A practical example: the boolean specifies whether to compress a buffer and you'd like to write uniform code that operates on `local` either way.

The above example, however, invoked Gizmo's copy-constructor on `arg` when `frobnicate` was `false`.
I managed to avoid the invocation of the copy-constructor by changing `Frobnicate(arg)` to `static_cast<const Gizmo&>(Frobnicate(arg))`.

My question becomes: how does the ternary operator interact with the rule about binding a local reference-to-const to a temporary? Is my solution legal and well-behaved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not well-behaved. For the lifetime extension to occur, the temporary must be bound directly to the reference. Once you add a cast, the binding is no longer direct, and the resulting reference becomes dangling.

We can see this with some simple testing code:

```
#include <iostream>
struct Gizmo
{
    ~Gizmo() { std::cout << "Gizmo destroyed\n"; }
};

Gizmo Frobnicate(const Gizmo& arg) { return arg; }

void ProcessGizmo(const Gizmo& arg, bool frobnicate)
{
    const Gizmo& local = frobnicate ? static_cast<const Gizmo&>(Frobnicate(arg)) : arg;
    // Perform some work on local
    (void) local;
    std::cout << "Processing\n";
}

int main(){
    Gizmo g;
    ProcessGizmo(g, true);
    std::cout << "Processed\n";
}
```

This [prints](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f6dc9bdc9bcd7f46):

```
Gizmo destroyed
Processing
Processed
Gizmo destroyed
```

That first `Gizmo destroyed` message is from the return value of `Frobnicate()`; it's being destroyed at the end of that line - without lifetime extension.

An obvious workaround is moving the processing into another function:

```
void DoProcessGizmo(const Gizmo& arg) { /* process the Gizmo */ }

void ProcessGizmo(const Gizmo& arg, bool frobnicate)
{
    return frobnicate ? DoProcessGizmo(Frobnicate(arg)) : DoProcessGizmo(arg);
}
```

Comment: What about "return DoProcessGizmo( frobnicate ? Frobnicate(arg) : arg );" This also seems to work as expected

Comment: That makes a copy that the OP is seeking to avoid.

Comment: Hum... you are right! But I'm pretty sure I've seen that copy avoided in some version of MSVC in the past... Not that I can reproduce it with a recent version though. Thanks! I have to go and avoid some copies now!

Comment: What about `return DoProcessGizmo( frobnicate ? static_cast< const Gizmo & >( Frobnicate( arg ) ) : arg );`?  I assume this is legal C++, with no undefined behavior (albeit uglier than having two independent calls to `DoProcessGizmo`).