# Is it OK to explicitly cast prvalue to const reference to avoid extra copy in ternary operator?

Tags: c++, conditional-operator, prvalue

Let's suppose we have some non-copyable and non-movable type `Foo`, and a function

```cpp
int f(const Foo& foo) {
  ... // somehow compute the result depending on the value of foo.
}
```

Now let's suppose we want want to call this function like this:

```cpp
const Foo foo1{ 42 };
bool condition = getCondition();
int result = f(condition ? foo : Foo{ 150 });
```

This won't compile because `foo` and `Foo{ 150 }` are of different value categories, so, by definition, the ternary operator will return a prvalue of type `Foo` - which means that `foo1` will need to be copied if `condition == true`, so this causes a compilation error.

However, C++ guarantees that temporary objects remain valid until the end of the expression, so we can instead write this:

```cpp
const Foo foo1{ 42 };
bool condition = getCondition();
int result = f(condition ? foo1 : static_cast<const Foo&>(Foo{ 150 });
```

Now the ternary operator returns `const Foo&`, and even if this reference refers to `Foo{ 150 }`, this temporary object will remain valid until the end of the expression. No copying/moving takes place, so this compiles.

Obviously, a safer option would be to just write:

```cpp
int result = condition ? f(foo1) : f(Foo{ 150 });
```

However, this can lead to a lot of boilerplate if there are additional parameters, and grows exponentially for multiple "conditional" parameters:

```cpp
int result = condition1
               ? (condition2 ? f(foo1, foo2) : f(foo1, Foo{ 222 }))
               : (condition2 ? f(Foo{ 111 }, foo2) : f(Foo{ 111 }, Foo{ 222 }));
```

The hack above allows a shorter form:

```cpp
int result = f( condition1 ? foo1 : static_cast<const Foo&>(Foo{ 111 }),
                condition2 ? foo2 : static_cast<const Foo&>(Foo{ 222 }) );
```

I understand that this is somewhat risk-prone, but am I correct that the code above is valid?

P.S. I also wonder whether the compiler generates O(N) or O(2^N) instructions when there are N such "conditional" parameters.

[Ternary operator and prolonging the lifetime of a temporary object via reference-to-const](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28644398/ternary-operator-and-prolonging-the-lifetime-of-a-temporary-object-via-reference) addresses a similar scenario, but the question there is whether the ternary operator itself prolongs the lifetime of a temporary - it doesn't.

Comment: Please provide [mcve] since I can't repro "do not compile": https://godbolt.org/z/rvx591q9K after fixing obvious  typos in your code.

Comment: @MarekR, I said that Foo must be non-copyable and non-movable.
Example: https://godbolt.org/z/rbovMofv6

The question is not limited to non-copyable types: I simply wanted to emphasize that the ternary operator causes an extra copy when used with a const reference and a prvalue.

Comment: Not an answer to your question whether the mentioned cast is legit, but a simple workaround: add an overload consuming `Foo` as rvalue: `int f(Foo&& foo) { return f(foo); }`. https://godbolt.org/z/v4o44c1be

Comment: [Lifetime of temporary object ends as the last step in evaluating the full-expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime#Temporary_object_lifetime). So when you have repeating boiler plate code best way to address this is to define helper function: https://godbolt.org/z/9dqqT1Y89

Comment: @MarekR, while the helper function removes the need for an explicit cast, it lacks the short circuit evaluation property of the conditional operator.  Not only this means that a redundant object (`Foo{ 150 }`) will be constructed half of the time, but also it's inapplicable for case like `f(foo_ptr ? *foo_ptr : Foo{ 150 })`.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/EbGsc5PMc