# error in invalid initialization of non-const reference type . Using c++ code in Linux OS. GCC Compiler

Tags: c++, gcc

`vector<string>& temp = var_obj.funct();` is not working in Linux but except `&` ITS WORKING FINE.
`vector<string> temp = var_obj.funct();`

> error :  invalid initialization of non-const reference of type
>   ‘std::vector,
>   std::allocator >, std::allocator, std::allocator > > >&’ from a temporary
>   of type ‘std::vector,
>   std::allocator >, std::allocator, std::allocator > > >’

Comment: This seems correct. Would you expect it to work differently? How would that work?

Comment: You can't bind a temporary object to a non-const reference.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the value returned by the function is temporary. You cannot generate a reference to it because it exists only temporarily. After the function call, the value is gone.

Instead, try this:

```
vector<string> temp = var_obj.funct();
vector<string> &temp2 = temp;
```

Now you have a reference with the name `temp2`.

Comment: You can generate a reference to it, but it has to be const.

Comment: Interesting. I tried to generate a const reference to it, and it works. I didn't know that. Does that reference refer to a valid object? If so, where in memory is that object located?

Comment: Answering myself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784262/does-a-const-reference-prolong-the-life-of-a-temporary helped.