# Why can some variables of reference type bind rvalues and some can't?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main() {

//int& a = 3; <- Doesn't compile. Expression must be lvalue.
const auto& c = 1 + 2; // c is a constant reference to an int. (?)
                       // compiles fine. 1+2 is a rvalue? what's going on?
cout << c << endl;

return 0;
}
```

I don't understand why the compiler wont raise a compilation error.
Since auto "forces" c to be a reference to a constant int, and references are refereed to lvalues, how come this works?

Comment: The different is between `int&` and `const int&`, the type-deduction by `auto` plays no part in this. Constant references can bind to rvalues.

Comment: More on the "most important const" here: http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does a const reference prolong the life of a temporary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784262/does-a-const-reference-prolong-the-life-of-a-temporary)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would indeed not work without the `const` -- you would get a compilation error.

But the `const` is there, i.e. you are not going to modify what `c` is referencing.

For this case, there is additional wording in the standard that the *temporary* value `c` is referencing (the result of `1 + 2`) will have its lifetime extended to the end of the lifetime of the reference.

This is quite unrelated to `auto`. It's the `const` that is making the difference here.