# Is there a sequence point between return and expression in return statement?

Tags: c++

Here is the quote from standard :

> The second context is when a reference is bound to a temporary. The
>   temporary to which the reference is bound or the temporary that is the
>   complete object to a subobject of which the temporary is bound
>   persists for the lifetime of the reference except as specified below.
>   A temporary bound to a reference member in a constructor’s
>   ctor-initializer (§12.6.2 [class.base.init]) persists until the
>   constructor exits. A temporary bound to a reference parameter in a
>   function call (§5.2.2 [expr.call]) persists until the completion of
>   the full expression containing the call.

Please look at the code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct foo{const char* bar ; foo(): bar("This is foo"){} };

foo returnByValue(){ return foo(); }
const foo& returnByConstRef() { return returnByValue();  }

int main() {
std::cout<< returnByConstRef().bar  <<std::endl; // is life of temp is extended in while this expression?
return 0;
}
```

is the above program valid? or **temp object in the following statement dies before return statement leaves the function?**

```
return returnByValue();
```

if so making the statement

```
const char*& jinjja = returnByConstRef().bar;
```

is invalid?

Comment: How on earth did you manage to quote the first two bullet points and miss the third?

Comment: @T.C. ROFL I feeling dumb now :D . Anyways question originated from this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784262/does-a-const-reference-prolong-the-life-of-a-temporary

Answer (score 2):

> The lifetime of a temporary bound to the returned value in a function return statement (6.6.3) is not
>   extended; the temporary is destroyed at the end of the full-expression in the return statement.

This should answer your question.

It may help to know that when a function returns, the order of events is as follows:

1. The return value (if any) is initialized by the expression in the `return` statement (if any). This initialization, which includes the evaluation of the expression, constitutes a *full-expression*.
2. Temporaries created in the `return` statement are destroyed (in reverse order of initialization). (This doesn't include the temporary introduced to hold the return value, in the case that the function's return type is not a reference.)
3. Automatic local variables  are destroyed (in reverse order of initialization).
4. Control returns to the caller. The *full-expression* containing the call completes evaluation.
5. If the function's declared return type is not a reference, the function call expression's value is a temporary. Said temporary, if not bound to a reference, is destroyed along with all the other temporaries created in the *full-expression* containing the call (in reverse order of initialization).

Comment: are you sure of your answer? see this post : http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/ . meh, I'm confused again, at which point exactly temp object `foo();` dies? . explain again, i am gonna cry now.

Comment: @AngelusMortis Sorry, I wasn't clear. The temporary introduced to hold the return value is considered to be formed in the calling expression, so it's not destroyed before the function returns.

Comment: can you use ASCII art demonstrate pleaseee? , I mean actual evens that are happening in my example code? Thanks