# Const reference doesn't prolongs the life of temp due to RVO?

Tags: c++

This is follow up of question [Is there a sequence point between return and expression in return statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32665221/is-there-a-sequence-point-between-return-and-expression-in-return-statement) . The answer-er isn't replying to my comments , neither I'm unable to understand from his answer, nor I know how to bump the thread. So I created this question, my sincere apologies for doing this.

Consider the below code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct foo{const char* bar ; foo(): bar("This is foo"){} };

foo returnByValue(){ return foo(); }
const foo& returnByConstRef() { return returnByValue();  } // *

int main() {
std::cout<< returnByConstRef().bar  <<std::endl; // is life of temp is extended in while this expression?
return 0;
}
```

My understanding is that `returnByValue()` expression (inside `returnByConstRef()`) is the copy of temporary object `foo()` (using copy ctor) . Now `returnByConstRef()` which is const reference to temp object returned by `returnByValue()` (copy of original `temp()` object in the code) , Now when I invoke `returnByConstRef().bar` why is it undefined behavior ?

Where is my thinking wrong? , does RVO does this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't due to RVO, the standard specifies that temporaries bound to returned values do not have their lifetime extended:

> `N3337 [class.temporary]/5:` [...] The temporary to which the reference is bound or the temporary that is the complete object of a subobject to which the reference is bound persists for the lifetime of the reference except:
>
> - [...]
> - **The lifetime of a temporary bound to the returned value in a function return statement (6.6.3) is not
>     extended; the temporary is destroyed at the end of the full-expression in the return statement.**
> - [...]

For your example:

```
const foo& returnByConstRef() 
{ 
    return returnByValue();  
}
```

`returnByValue()` is a temporary which is being bound to the return value, kind of like this:

```
const foo& returnByConstRef() 
{ 
    const foo& _temporary_object = returnByValue();
    return _temporary_object;  
    //object referenced by _temporary_object is destroyed
}
```

Such temporaries do *not* have their lifetime extended; they are destroyed on function exit. Maybe it would help you to think of it like this:

```
function returnByConstRef
    call returnByValue, put value on the stack
    put pointer to value in return register
    clear up stack, invalidating pointer to the value
```

Comment: please use easy language with example, I don't follow standard's language in this case. Your answer is very similar to the question link I posted in very start of this thread. sorry for my english also

Comment: I wrote my thinking in the question , can you please tell where am I wrong and contradict me? :) Thanks.

Comment: The bold paragraph basically says: "The lifetime of a temporary returned by a function cannot be extended.". There's nothing wrong with your understanding of the code, the C++ standard just says that what you're trying to do is not allowed. It may even accidentally compile & work but there is no guarantee what will happen (a.k.a. undefined behavior). 
In case you're wondering why the standard forbids you from doing this, I have no clue, maybe someone else does.

Comment: @Excelcius you're overgeneralizing what the bold paragraph states. it talks about temporaries *bound* to return values

Comment: so the `_temporary_object` is deleted when function `returnByConstRef()` exits in your example code, right? Thanks

Comment: @AngelusMortis the object referenced by `_temporary_object` is destroyed when the function exits, yes.

Comment: now since `_temporary_object` is deleted, object referenced by it also get deleted. now I get it.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki I know, but OP wanted easy language because it seems he had troubles understanding this paragraph. That's why I left out parts which should be clear in the context of this question.

Comment: @AngelusMortis note that there is a distinction in C++ between *deleted* and *destroyed*. Deleting usually refers to a `delete` expression on some pointer, whereas destruction usually refers to a variable coming to the end of its lifetime.

Comment: got it @TartanLlama Thanks again for answer. I wished I could upvote your answer more than 1 time :)