# C++ Empty Pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11

So I am new to C++ and I am trying to use an inner class like this:

```
struct PreviousButton {
    SelectionScreen* ss;

    PreviousButton(SelectionScreen* sss) {
        ss = sss;
    }

    void ClickAction() {
        //images is a vector with images. in here it is empty
        ss->images;
    }
};
```

This inner class is inside the class SelectionScreen and I need to perform a click action and need some of the variables of the selectionscreen.

SelectionScreen:

```
class SelectionScreen {
public:
    void AddImage(Image img);
    std::vector<Image> images;
```

How I fill the vector:

```
Image* image = new Image{ };
AddImage(*image2);
```

AddImage method:

```
void SelectionScreen::AddImage(Image img)
{
    images.push_back(img);
}
```

But when I try to use the selectionscreen inside the class all of the variables are empty. But when I look into selectionscreen all of the variables are set.

The way I pass the SelectionScreen:

```
PreviousButton* previousButton = new PreviousButton(*ren, this);
```

How SelectionScreen gets initialized: (this method is called from the main)

```
int Program::Render() {
    bool quit = false;
    MenuScreen m = SelectionScreen{ Sdl_Renderer };
    // change current screen to selectionscreen
    ScreenController::GetInstance().ChangeMenu(m);

    while (!quit) {
    // handle user input and repaint
    }

    // delete all windows if quit is true
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(Sdl_Renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(Sdl_Window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Does anyone knows why my variables are empty?

Comment: Apart from the fact that I see too many pointers, have you initialized `ss` inside `PreviousButton`s constructor?

Comment: There are no inner classes here. Perhaps you mean a data member of a class type. Also please describe what you mean by empty variable.

Comment: Sounds like he's talking about subclassing AbstactUIComponent. It's a not an inner class, it is PreviousButton's base class.

Comment: @PaoloM I did not initialize ss, but if im right it is a pointer and it doesn't need to be initialized?

Comment: @n.m. with empty variable I mean. I have a vector<Image> in my selectionscreen class and I put 2 images in the vector. When I try to get an image out of the vector inside PreviousButton. The vector is empty, so it doesn't contain any image

Comment: @JellevanEs is this question about `SDL_Renderer& ren`? That's the only reference that I see in your code.

Comment: @user2079303 O sorry I mistyped something I guess. Its about the SelectionScreen, passed as "this". Those variables are empty.

Comment: @JellevanEs well, if this question is not about references, then i recommend you come up with a more descriptive title and get rid of the irrelevant tag. You should also create a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You never mention `vector` (the single most relevant detail) anywhere in your post and, most importantly, anywhere in your code. Please try to include relevant details in your question.

Comment: @n.m. I updated my question I hope it is clear enough now.

Comment: @JellevanEs When you say the `vector` is empty, how do you know this? From the debugger? Or by printing `images.size()`?

Comment: @atkins I used the debugger to check what objects were in the vector.

Comment: You say "I look here... I look there". It's not clear how exactly you look. Please describe what you actually do (e.g. "I type `foobar` in the debugger") and what actually happens (e.g. "the debugger prints `barfoo`").

Comment: Unrelated but important: `mage* image = new Image{ };
AddImage(*image2);` looks like a memory leak (unless you use the pointer later on).

Comment: @JellevanEs There's nothing obviously wrong with `struct PreviousButton`. I would suggest showing us more details of `class SelectionScreen`, especially around the calls to `AddImage` and the creation of `previousButton` (e.g. what do you do with `previousButton` after you created it?).

Comment: @atkins i don't do anything relevant with the `previousButton`. The only thing I do after I create it is: `previousButton->SetDimensions(100, 10, 75, 75);
 previousButton->SetLocation(100, 282);
 AddUIComponent(previousButton);` This are just some things I have to do to make sure it gets drawed by SDL

Comment: @JellevanEs Actually, probably more important is how you create and store the `ScreenSelection` - can you show us that code? The problem you are seeing suggests the `ScreenSelection` has been deleted between you creating it and invoking `PreviousButton::ClickAction()`.

Comment: @atkins I added a code snippet I hope this gives you enough information. If not please let me know

Comment: @JellevanEs Yes, I think it does - see my updated answer.

Comment: @JellevanEs Sorry, think my original update was not correct. There's a further update now. Fortunately, the solution is the same, but I think my original explanation was wrong.

Comment: @atkins Thank you for your help so far. Right now I can't edit my code. As soon as I am home I will test your answer. I will let you know what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't addressing the immediate issue you describe, but you have a serious problem here:

```
  ss->currentImageIndex = ss->images.capacity() - 1;
```

`images.capacity() - 1` is not guaranteed to return a valid index into your `vector`. You should use `images.size() - 1`.

`std::vector::capacity()` tells you the storage space currently allocated for the `vector`, not the number of elements it actually contains.

**UPDATE**

When you assign a `SelectionScreen` to a `MenuScreen` like this

```
MenuScreen m = SelectionScreen{ Sdl_Renderer };
```

you "slice" the `SelectionScreen` object (see [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/274626/995218)).

This line creates a new `MenuScreen` object, `m`, by copy-constructing it from a temporary `SelectionScreen` object. The new `MenuScreen` object, `m`, is **not** a `SelectionScreen`. It is also a completely distinct object from the temporary `SelectionScreen` created on the right-hand side of this expression.

Your `PreviousButton`, which I assume is created in the constructor of `SelectionScreen`, holds a pointer to the temporary `SelectionScreen`, which the compiler is free to delete once this line has completed.

To fix this, you could use this initialisation instead:

```
MenuScreen& m = SelectionScreen{ Sdl_Renderer };
```

In this case, `m` is a reference to your (temporary) `SelectionScreen` - this is good because (a) references are polymorphic, so it still knows that it's really a `SelectionScreen`, not just a `MenuScreen` and (b) it's a reference to the exact same `SelectionScreen` object created on the right-hand side, which your `PreviousButton` has a pointer to. I've also bracketed the "temporary" bit now, because taking a local reference to a temporary guarantees it will exist for as long as the reference does (see e.g. [Does a const reference prolong the life of a temporary?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2784262/995218)).

Note that I am assuming here that you only make use of this `SelectionScreen` within the `while (!quit)` loop that follows, i.e. the screen can safely be deleted at the end of this `int Program::Render()` method.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Till now it worked great but I didn't know this. I will change it.

Comment: Thank you very much your solution works. Just one more question. `MenuScreen& m = SelectionScreen{}` works. But does it also work if I just do `SelectionScreen m = SelectionScreen{}` ?

Comment: That will "almost certainly" also work. When the type on the left of `=` is the same as the type constructed on the right the compiler will is allowed to use "copy elision" which means no temporary will be constructed (I'll refer you to my question on that subject here! http://stackoverflow.com/q/33086346/995218). However, if you want to be absolutely sure you could just write `SelectionScreen m{Sdl_Renderer};`, to make it explicit that you don't expect a copy constructor to be called.

Comment: By the way, I also discovered today that `MenuScreen& m = SelectionScreen{ Sdl_Renderer };` is not supported by most compilers - I think only Visual Studio will allow it. Sounds like it worked for you, but if you want to be sure your code is portable you should use `const MenuScreen& m = SelectionScreen{ Sdl_Renderer };` i.e. use a `const` reference. However, that may cause a problem if `ScreenController::ChangeMenu()` requires a non-const reference. Anyway, `SelectionScreen m{Sdl_Renderer};` solves all these problems, so I would just go with that.