# In S s = S() is it guaranteed that no temporary will be created?

Tags: c++, constructor, language-lawyer, temporary

In the following code, are `pS` and `s.pS` guaranteed to be equal in the final line? In other words, in the statement `S s = S();`, can I be sure that a temporary `S` will not be constructed?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct S
{
  S() { pS = this; }
  S* pS;
};

int main()
{
  S s = S();
  S* pS = &s;
  cout << pS << " " << s.pS << endl;
}
```

In every compiler I've tested this in `pS == s.pS`, but I'm not sufficiently familiar with the standard to be able to satisfy myself that this is guaranteed.

Comment: No - it is a temporary which might get optimized out

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, you can assume that it will be RVO and only need worry about it if you have special circumstances that demand special treatment or performance guarantees.  Otherwise, this is virtually guaranteed and should be used.

Comment: @Mordachai This has nothing to do with RVO. The R stands for return. There is no return here.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**NO**

The compiler isn't *obligated* to do copy elision. The standard simply specifies that, [class.copy]:

> When certain criteria are met, an implementation **is allowed to** omit the copy/move construction of a class object [...]

I can disable copy elision via `-fno-elide-constructors`, and then the two pointers will definitely be different. For example:

```
$g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -fno-elide-constructors -Wall -Wextra main.cpp && ./a.out
0x7fff5a598920 0x7fff5a598930
```

And in the general case, if we add `S(S&& ) = delete`, then the above code wouldn't even compile.

Comment: I thought C++11 or 13 made this mandatory.
And even so - I believe it is in the category of "virtually guaranteed" and "best practices" not to worry about this anymore (with the normal caveat of: if you do performance testing, and find that this is an actual issue is a hot code path, then and only then would you manually involve yourself in optimizing this manually)...

Comment: @Mordachai Nope. The wording I quoted is from N4527.

Comment: @Mordachai It is absolutely not "best practice" to not worry about this!

Comment: @Mordachai: What is C++13?

Comment: I guess I was wrong.  Ah well.  I really had taken from some C++ conferences that `type x = ctor(initializers)` and `type x(initializers);` were identical as far as the compiler was concerned.  But... I'm just going from memory from the '14 Beyond C++ conference - and my memory is fallible.  C++13 is also irrelevant - there were various possibilities to what would follow C++11, 13 was just one unofficial possibility that became C++14 when it slipped into '14.

Answer (score 11):

Most compilers performs what's called [copy/move elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision), which is specified by the C++ standard. But it is not guaranteed. For example, you can compile with `-fno-elide-constructors` in gcc and you'll see *all* constructors in all their glory.

<kbd>[Live example on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c5576dc1bce7298c)</kbd>

Answer (score 5):

There is no guarantee that there will be no temporary. But the Big Three compilers will optimize it out (even with the `-O0` switch).

To guarantee no temporary at all just write:

```
int main()
{
  // ...
  S s{};
  // ...
}
```

Or simply `S s;`.