# Storing return value as a const reference versus as a value

Tags: c++, const-reference

Suppose that a function has the signature

```
std::string GetString();
```

and that it returns a new string by value. Now given the following code:

```
// (a) Store the return value to a const reference.
const std::string& my_string = GetString();

// (b) Store the return value to a (const) value.
const std::string my_string = GetString();
```

Am I correct to understand that (a) and (b) are, from a C++11 compiler's point of view, identical? If so, is there a rough consensus on the choice of style?

Comment: I would be surprised if they were identical. In the case b, you actually have a std::string. In case a, you have a reference to a string, but no actual std::string storage. It should crash, or perhaps even fail to compile.

Comment: @ChrisBecke [This Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784262/does-a-const-reference-prolong-the-life-of-a-temporary) explains the case (a).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I correct to understand that (a) and (b) are, from a C++11 compiler's point of view, identical?

No, they are not identical.

(a) extends the life of the temporary object returned by `GetString()`.

(b) makes a new object. It is constructed by:

1. invoking the copy constructor of `std::string` by using the return value of `GetString()` as the argument,
2. being assigned the return value of `GetString()` by RTO, or
3. invoking the move constructor using the return value of `GetString()`.

Comment: A couple nits: (a) doesn't "extend the life of the temporary".  The temporary created by the return value of `GetString` is gone and (a) is a reference to a temporary that no longer exists.  (b) may or may not invoke the copy constructor due to the return value optimization (since forever) or due to move semantics (C++11 or later) where the value constructed by `GetString()` is directly moved into the storage declared in (b) without invoking the copy constructor.

Comment: @legalize, agree with you on (b), not on (a). See [Does a const reference prolong the life of a temporary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784262/does-a-const-reference-prolong-the-life-of-a-temporary)

Comment: @R Sahu OK, I see your point about (a). However, this feels like an edge condition that is harder to remember than it is to avoid.  The return value optimization/move semantics comes up much more often and is more useful to understand IMO.

Comment: @legalize, it's a feature of the language that is useful when you need to simply query the returned object for useful information. The type - `const&` - should be a clear reminder of the purpose of the object.

Comment: @legalize reference binding is very common in C++ and essential to understand. Actually all references (i.e. rvalue references also) extend lifetime of a temporary if they are legally bound

Comment: @M.M I understand references and how they bind.  However, in 20 years of C++ programming I can't say that the **lifetime extension** property of references has come up as something that you need to know about on a daily basis.  Now that we're discussing it, this bit of esoterica feels familiar, but as I say I just don't see memorizing it as something that is coming up every day.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically they are different, but practically they are identical. The only code you can write to tell the difference would involve `decltype(my_string)`.

The compiler could generate the same assembly for both.