# Transfer the ownership of a returning unique_ptr from functions

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

```
class A{};

void use(const A&){}

unique_ptr<A> my_fun(){
    return make_unique<A>();
}

int main(){
    const A& rA = *my_fun();    //Error: object will be destructed
    use(rA);

    const auto rA1 = my_fun();    //make a copy of the unique_ptr. transfer the ownership
    use(*rA1);

    const auto& rA2 = my_fun();    
    use(*rA2);

    return 0;
}
```

`rA` doesn't work because the returning pointer will be destructed. `rA1` works fine, because the transferring of the ownership preserves the object. My question is about `rA2`. It's an alias of the returning `unique_ptr`, right? Why the object is not destroyed, like in the  case of `rA`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does a const reference prolong the life of a temporary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784262/does-a-const-reference-prolong-the-life-of-a-temporary)