# An rvalue reference in C++ prolongs the life of a temporary object

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference, temporary-objects

With the Stack Overflow question *[Does a const reference prolong the life of a temporary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784262/does-a-const-reference-prolong-the-life-of-a-temporary)*, I understand how a const reference prolongs the life of a temporary object.

I know an rvalue reference can prolong the life of a temporary object too, but I don't know if there is some difference.

So if I code like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Sandbox
{
public:
    Sandbox(string&& n) : member(n) {}
    const string& member;
};

int main()
{
    Sandbox sandbox(string("four"));
    cout << "The answer is: " << sandbox.member << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Will it work or will it have the same error like the link above?

What if I code like the following?

```
class Sandbox
{
public:
    Sandbox(string&& n) : member(move(n)) {}
    const string&& member;
};
```

Will it work?

Comment: the lifetime of temporary matches the lifetime of the reference that binds directly to it, which is `n`  (not `member`)

Comment: @M.M Will `string&& member` make sense?

Comment: @M.M I meant does changing `member` rvalue reference make OP's code valid? Does the temporary `string("four")` 's life prolonged until the cout statement?

Comment: @songyuanyao no, the lifetime of temporary matches the lifetime of `n`, not `member`

Comment: @M.M So OP's code is still ill-formed?

Comment: @songyuanyao  well, I dont think you can change `member` into rvalue ref. Because `n` is a left reference. `int &&rr1 = 42; int &&rr2 = rr1; // error, rr1 is a left value`.

Comment: It's well-formed but causes undefined behaviour

Comment: @M.M   I don't quite understand "binds directly to it". What if I code this:`const int & r = 6; func(r);` And here is the func: `void func(const int &n){}`. does "binds directly to it" mean that `n` in the func is undefined behaviour?

Comment: @Thomas no, because the temporary's lifetime matches `r`, and `n`'s lifetime is a subset of `r`

Comment: Is it because `6` is always there so `func` can work whereas `string("four")` will be free after the ctor?

Comment: no, nothing like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `string("four")` temporary exists for the duration of the constructor call (this is explained in the answer to the linked question). Once the object is constructed, this temporary gets destroyed. The reference in the class is now a reference to a destroyed object. Using the reference results in undefined behavior.

The use of the rvalue reference, here, makes no difference.

Comment: what if I use `std::move` like this: `Sandbox(string&& n) : member(std::move(n)) {}
    const string&& member;`

Comment: @Thomas makes no difference

Comment: @Yves `std::move` is a cast. it does not move. and anyway to move you'd have to move in a value type.