# Initializer list and const& - is this legal C++

Tags: c++, reference, temporary-objects

Consider:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class A
{
public:
    const int& i;    
};

class B
{
public:
    const std::vector<int>& i;
};

int main()
{
    A a = { 3 };
    std::cout << a.i << std::endl;

    B b = { { 1, 2 } };
    std::cout << b.i[0] << " " << b.i[1] << std::endl;
}
```

On VS2015 update 3, this crashes in runtime on the last line because the vector b.i is empty; on gcc (4.9.2) this runs OK and shows the expected output (3 1 2). So on VS it 'works' (does what I expected) for an int, but not a vector.

Is this a VS bug or is it just an accident that it works on gcc?

Comment: It's pretty clearly undefined behavior. You have references bound to temporaries which are destroyed shortly afterwards. "Seems to work" is one possible manifestation of UB.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784262/does-a-const-reference-prolong-the-life-of-a-temporary. That question involves constructor call, but this one is about aggregate initialization.

Comment: The draft standard actually has a similar [example](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#6): `struct S { int mi; const std::pair<int,int>& mp; };
S a { 1, {2,3} };`.

Answer (score 1):

The first is OK, temporary's lifetime is extended when assigned to a reference. Second is UB AFAIK, because `{ { 1, 2 } }` is a `std::initializer_list<>`, not a `std::vector<>` directly. Prolonging lifetime temporary objects is not transitive (i.e., it lasts till the end of *current* function, in this case, the constructor), only local ones get prolonged.

Answer (score 1):

It works on gcc by accident, because this is definitely undefined behavior.

In order to satisfy `B`'s initialization, the compiler needs to construct a temporary `vector<int>`. Since the reference to that vector is `const`, the compiler does not see a problem with using it to initialize `B`. However, the temporary object becomes invalid as soon as the initialization is over, so accessing it by reference outside of initialization is undefined behavior.