# Reference count for a reference to shared_pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I understand that the `shared_ptr` class automatically manages dynamic objects.

Here, I have a function `f` that returns a `const shared_ptr<int>` to an `int 2`.

I have two versions of `main` that differ in one place. Version A saves the return value of `f` into a **shared pointer**, while version B saves into **shared pointer reference**.

```
 using namespace std;
    const std::shared_ptr<int> f() {
        const std::shared_ptr<int> ret = std::make_shared<int>(2);
        return ret;
    }

    int main () {
        const std::shared_ptr<int> p = f();     // A
        // const std::shared_ptr<int> &p = f(); // B
        cout << p.use_count() << *p << endl; // prints 1 2
        return 0;
    }
```

Both versions print `1 2`. I am okay with version A because `p` is the last `shared_ptr` pointing at the `int`, therefore `use_count` is `1`.

Question: Why is `use_count` equal to `1` for version B? Where is the last existing `shared_ptr`?

Comment: Reference counts for `std::shared_ptr`'s apply to instances, not to references.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thank you. For version A, is the instance `p`? For version B, which is the existing instance? Is it the return value of `f()`? Maybe I did not fully understand references, which I thought is an alias of an object.

Comment: temporary lifetime extands with const reference.

Comment: Related question that answers you question as well as point out relevant C++ Standard passages: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784262/does-a-const-reference-prolong-the-life-of-a-temporary

Comment: What do you think the reference is a reference *to*?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I think the reference refers to the temporary return value of `f()`. From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime): The lifetime of a temporary object may be extended by binding to a const lvalue reference. Thanks @Jarod42 and @tkleczek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ if you assign a temporary directly into a `&&` or `const&`, reference lifetime extension kicks in and the temporary lasts as long as reference does.

This only works when your reference is a local variable<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> Or in certain cases in certain compilers where you use aggregate construction of `struct`s.  But don't use that, because it is one of the spots where a "transparent" forwarding constructor behaves fundamentally different than an aggregate, so otherwise innocuous changes later can break your code.