# Simple version of `std::function`: lifetime of function object?

Tags: c++, lambda

I tried to build a very simple version of `std::function`. Below the code of a very first version. My question is about the lifetime of the temporary object from the lambda-expression, because I'm actually storing a reference to it. Or is the lifetime of the object prolonged?

It tried to use a copy of the function (`T mf` instead of `const T& mf` inside `struct F`), but that gives an error due to the decaying of the function to a pointer.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct F {
    F(const T& f) : mf{f} {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
    }
    void test() {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
        mf();
    }
    const T& mf;
};

template<typename T>
struct F<T*> {
    F(T f) : mf{f} {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
    }
    void test() {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
        mf();
    }
    T* mf;
};

void g() {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
}

int main() {
    F<void(void)> f1(g);
    f1.test();

    auto g1 = g;

    F f2(g1);
    f2.test();

    F f3([](){ // lifetime?
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
    });
    f3.test();

    auto l1 = [](){
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
    };
    F f4(l1);
    f4.test();
}
```

Comment: You indeed have lifetime issue.

Comment: Do you see a way to solve this?

Comment: Try [`std::decay_t<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay)

Comment: You are using pointers and references. None of them ensure lifetime of the object being pointed. Variable `f3` has a lambda as an argument but this lamda creates a temporary variable which cannot be referenced (try moving instead). Even if you take a pointer from it it still will be destroyed when expression is evaluated (not until the end of scope even).

Comment: Solved: `std::decay_t<T>` declares the member as function-pointer if `T` is a function. Otherwise it leaves `T` as it was. So in every case a copy ist made! And I don't have to use the partial specialization anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do have lifetime problems here: [lifetime extension thanks to `const` only applies for *local* `const` references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784262/does-a-const-reference-prolong-the-life-of-a-temporary).

You need to make sure that the referenced function lives at least as long as the wrapper, or you need to copy/move the function into the wrapper.

---

> but that gives an error due to the decaying of the function to a pointer

You can use [`std::decay_t<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay) to ensure that you're copying/moving objects *(e.g. closures)* into the wrapper.