# C++11: 'decltype class instance declaration' with std::move( ) doesn't call 'move constructor.' Why?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, decltype, stdmove

I recently started using **c++** and I chose to learn **c++11** features.
But how c++ codes run is sometimes not so tangible.

below is my code. 
At the part with `decltype(std::move(sample)) sample2 = std::move(sample);` I'm not sure why this line doesn't call move constructor.
Could you explain why?

```
#include <iostream>

class AAA
{
   public:
      AAA() { std::cout << "default constructor" << std::endl; }
      AAA(const AAA& cs) { std::cout << "copy constructor" << std::endl; }
      AAA(AAA&& cs) { std::cout << "move constructor" << std::endl; }
      ~AAA() { std::cout << "destructor" << std::endl; }
};

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    AAA sample;
// ((right here))
    decltype(std::move(sample)) sample2 = std::move(sample); 
    return 0;
}
```

It is compiled on [ ubuntu 16.04 LTS ] with [ gcc 5.4.0 ]

original code : https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/tALvLuSNbN

Comment: @user202729 pretty sure the `= std::move(sample)` has nothing to do with the `decltype`

Comment: That line is `AAA&& sample2 = std::move(sample);` which isn't supposed to cause a construction any more than `AAA& sample2 = sample;`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux that should be an answer

Comment: @user202729 thanks for your advice

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux :) Thx. Your answer seems clear. I'll try to understand that sentence... maybe by googling??

Comment: @KiseongYoo Let me know what part is confusing you and I'll try to form an answer.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I think I'm confused with lvalue/rvalue. => in my code { const int& x7 = -7; } is x7 rvalue? that's why assigning int(rvalue) to x7 succeeded?? similarily decltype(std::move(sample)) == AAA&& so sample2 becomes rvalue? then { auto sample3 = std::move(sample); } works because rvalue can be assigned to lvalue, right?

Comment: @KiseongYoo If it has a name or it's address can be taken, then it's not an `rvalue`. `x7` clearly has a name so it cannot be an rvalue. `-7` is an integer literal and is a prvalue (a type of rvalue).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux { const int& x7 } is an lvalue. I missed it.

Comment: @KiseongYoo You should be aware of an exception in the language which allows temporaries to be bound to `const T &`, which in some cases can extend the lifetime of the temporary. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784262/does-a-const-reference-prolong-the-life-of-a-temporary).

Comment: Welcome to SO. It will good for you learn how to create a [mcve] when you run into a problem. Such an example demonstrating your question can be seen at https://ideone.com/vs2rge.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux woow, I didn't know that. thanks :)

Comment: @RSahu should I modify my code?

Comment: @KiseongYoo, I would say, yes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function `std::move<T>` returns a `T &&`, so for `std::move(sample)` it returns `AAA &&`. This is an [rvalue reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Rvalue_references) and behave a lot like an [lvalue reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Lvalue_references) (a type like `AAA &` would be an lvalue reference) in that they both are alias to objects that already exist.

It's important to understand that `std::move` does *not* in itself cause anything to be moved. It simply returns an rvalue reference to the argument it's given. For example `std::move(foo);` alone does absolutely nothing. It's only when the result is used to initialize or assign to an object that it becomes useful.

For example `auto bar = std::move(foo);` will return an rvalue reference to `foo` and use that reference to call `bar`'s constructor.

To answer the question, since `std::move(sample)` returns a `AAA &&`, the line in question is the same as `AAA && sample2 = std::move(sample);`. The behavior is practically the same as `AAA & sample2 = sample;`. In both cases, you are initializing a reference to an existing object and no new object needs to be constructed.

If your goal is to move `sample` into a new `AAA`, the correct line would be `auto sample2 = std::move(sample);` like you do with `sample3`. Though beware that the line `sample3` is moving from an already moved-from `sample`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your elaborate answer. Now I understand what's happening under the hood. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

Your snippet expands to

```
AAA&& sample2 = std::move(sample);
```

which binds an rvalue (the result of `std::move(sample)`) to an rvalue reference (`sample2`). No new object is constructed, and hence no such constructor is called.

Comment: Do note that it's UB when the expression doesn't point to some object with long lifetime.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer :) The line does "bind rvalue to a rvalue reference." I see.