# GCC anonymous is uninitialised

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, variadic-templates, compiler-flags

I'm trying to create something similar to `std::tuple`, a sort of compile-time list using variadic templates and recursive inheritance as shown in the implementation below.

My problem would be that although the implementation shown below works fine on msvc, clang and icc `ConstExprList::Get` always returns 0 on gcc(trunk version).

If compile the code with -Wall -Werror options enabled, gcc throws the following error:

`anonymous is used uninitialized in this function [-Werror=uninitialized]`.

Note that with optimizations disabled the error does not occur.

Is this a bug in the gcc implementation or am missing something?

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename... Args>
class ConstExprList;

template <typename Head, typename... Tail>
class ConstExprList<Head, Tail...> : public ConstExprList<Tail...>
{
public:
    ConstExprList(const Head& head, const Tail&... tail) : ConstExprList<Tail...>(tail...),  m_head(head) {}

    template <std::size_t Idx>
    inline typename std::enable_if<Idx == 0, Head>::type Get(void) const noexcept
    {
        return m_head;
    }

    template <std::size_t Idx>
    inline typename std::enable_if<Idx != 0, Head>::type Get(void) const noexcept
    {
        return ConstExprList<Tail...>::template Get<Idx - 1>();
    }

private:
    const Head& m_head;
};

template <typename Head>
class ConstExprList<Head>
{
public:
    ConstExprList(const Head& head) : m_head(head) {}

    template <std::size_t Idx>
    inline auto Get(void) const noexcept
    {
        static_assert(Idx == 0, "Index out of range");
        return m_head;
    }

private:
    const Head& m_head;
};

int main(void)
{
    ConstExprList<int, int> l(7, 3);

    return l.Get<0>();
}
```

Comment: Why not just use a constexpr tuple?

Comment: @n.m. It was just an exercise, but now that i found his problem i can't relax until i know what's causing it.

Comment: @n.m. As i mentioned in the question on clang works fine, only gcc seems to emit the error

Comment: @Lorand That's misleading though. GCC would have just issued a warning (which wouldn't affect conformance even if the warning were incorrect), except you specifically asked it to make all warnings an error.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. ideone seems broken today, gcc doesn't work at all.

Comment: cannot reproduce on [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/o09fXak5LPnnnenZ)

Comment: @appleapple Warnings about uninitialised variables only show up when optimisations are enabled.

Comment: @appleapple Oh, i forgot to mention that with optimisations disabled there is no error.

Comment: @hvd @ Lorand thanks, I don't know it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The warning is misleading but points out a real problem. `m_head` is a reference initialised to a temporary. This is not one of the contexts that will cause the temporary's lifetime to be extended, so your references are left dangling.

Comment: I also found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784262/does-a-const-reference-class-member-prolong-the-life-of-a-temporary

It's interesting, but this makes me even more confused. Why does it work then with calng and msvc?

Comment: @Lorand One of the possible consequences of undefined behaviour is that it behaves exactly the way you expect.

Comment: And if these kinf of initialisations don't prolong the lifespan, how/why do expression templates work?

Comment: @Lorand expression templates take care not to store references to temporaries ;) One can e.g. overload for rvalue references and store copies.