# Storing return value from function to const ref

Tags: c++, c++11

Function GetVec return std::vector. Then I store the returned value into the const ref. Does the returned value stored in const ref get destroyed in next line. I was in the impression it wont.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

std::vector<int> GetVec(){
  std::vector<int> vec;

  vec.push_back(1);
  vec.push_back(2);
  vec.push_back(3);

  return vec;
}


void print(const std::vector<int>& arg){
  for(const auto& id : arg){
    std::cout <<id << ",";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main(){
  const std::vector<int>& ret_val = GetVec();

  // is content of ret_val undefined here?
  print(ret_val);
}
```

Output :

1,2,3,

Comment: This is legal code. The `const ref` will remain valid in its own scope, which for your  case is the entire `main()`

Comment: [Does a const reference class member prolong the life of a temporary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784262/does-a-const-reference-class-member-prolong-the-life-of-a-temporary)

Comment: Tell me if the dupe is wrong

Comment: In your example, ret_val vector is destroyed when your main class ends.