# Returning a pointer to a member and assigning it to a reference. Is it legal?

Tags: c++, reference, temporary-objects

I'm reviewing code and which looks kind of wrong to me.
I know it can be written in another way and I know it is probably useless to write it this way.
Still, I was surprised that the compiler didn't generate any error/warning so I wonder if it is legal and why.

```
struct A
{
    int val = 0;
    int* GetVal() {
        return &val;
    }
};

void main()
{
    A a;
    int* const& r = a.GetVal();
}
```

AFAIK, a reference represents a real variable. The reference and the variable should both have the same memory address.
In this example, there is no variable holding the address (maybe a temporary?) so which variable does `r` refer to?

If I remove the `const` it doesn't compile.

Comment: Where is the instantiation of `a` actually? Your example is incomplete.

Comment: That's exactly the same for `int f(); int const& n = f();`...

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2784304/1312382). Context of the question there actually is a bit different, but the answer fits for your question as well (prolongation of life-time via const local references).

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ Thanks. fixed.

Comment: In this case `r` refers to the pointer. The pointer points at an instance of `A::val`

Comment: @user4581301 yes indeed, but the pointer is defined implicitly by the compiler (and not by me) and is hidden in the stack.

Comment: Hidden somewhere, probably the stack. Might sit in a register since you're not taking the pointer's address. Automatic storage can get a bit weird.

Answer (score 6):

There's one special case with references: a const reference is allowed to be bound to a temporary object, and it extends the lifetime of that temporary. Non-const references can't do this magic.

In your code, `GetVal()` returns a pointer by value, that is it returns a temporary pointer object. When used as a const reference initializer, the compiler stores that pointer value somewhere (most likely in the current stack frame) and binds the reference to that location.

Comment: +1 I didn't know this was possible. But this means that the usage/functionality of a const reference to a temporary are **exactly the same** as just copying the value? Except that you cannot overwrite the reference, where just storing the object would allow you to do so?

Comment: @Igor G thanks for the super quick response. I checked the stack the "hidden" variable is indeed there. I just wondered if it is legal.

Comment: @Gils Beware that this only works in certain situations. Only `const T &` allow it and only local references. For example, a reference type class member won't work this way.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux, I would say that const reference can help _avoiding_ making a copy. Consider passing a temporary object to `f(Type)` and `f(const Type&)`.

Comment: @François Andrieux I don't think I ever used this feature (at least not in this way). That's why it looks so wrong to me. I find the reference mark redundant in this case. I was just surprised it is legal.

Comment: @Gils You're using it (maybe without knowing) everytime you pass a `"text"` to a function requiring a `const std::string&`, a `std::string` temporary gets created and it's lifetime is extended for the duration of the function call.

Comment: @Mirko Indeed. Coming to think about, I use it a lot. Each time I pass an rvalue to a const reference parameter. But never like in this example. I still find this use of reference like in this example, useless.