# Struct initialization is overwriting a different struct, but only the last one

Tags: c++, reference, c++17, temporary-objects

Sorry for the confusing title, but I have absolutely no idea what is going on here. I'm making a generic tree struct in C++, but some of my values are overwriting others, but in a very specific way that I don't know how to search for. `node.h` is at the bottom of the question for reference.

This code in `main.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "node.h"

int main() {
    Node<std::string> a("a");
    std::cout << a.value << '\n';

    Node<std::string> b("b");
    std::cout << a.value << '\n';

    Node<std::string> c("c");
    std::cout << a.value << '\n';

    Node<std::string> d("d");
    std::cout << a.value << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

prints:

```
a
a
a
d
```

However, removing the two lines before the `return` prints:

```
a
a
c
```

The `node.h` file:

```cpp
#ifndef NODE
#define NODE

#include <vector>

template <class T>
struct Node {
    Node(const T& value);

    const T& value;
    std::vector<const Node<T>*> children;
};

template <class T>
Node<T>::Node(const T& value): value(value) {}

#endif
```

I have no idea what's happening here. Apologies if this is a duplicate, but I have absolutely no idea how to look up this problem.

Comment: Member `value` should be `std::string`, not `const std::string&`. You're trying (and failing) to lengthen the life of a temporary beyond the constructor to which it was passed, and that doesn't work. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784262/does-a-const-reference-class-member-prolong-the-life-of-a-temporary).

Comment: Thank you both for your quick replies, that fixed my issue.