# Why does this C++ program capturing lambda argument by reference segfault?

Tags: c++, gcc, lambda

Here is a minimal program that segfaults with gcc-8.3.0, compiled with `-std=c++2a`:

```
struct Command {
    double x;
};

template <typename T>
struct AutoBrake {
    AutoBrake(const T& publish) : publish{ publish } {}
    const T& publish;
};

int main()
{
    int count{};
    AutoBrake brake{ [&count](const Command&) {
        count += 1;
    } };

    brake.publish(Command{ 1.1f });
}
```

Debugging shows that it crashes when accessing the `count` reference inside the lambda expression when running `brake.publish`.

However if the command struct does not contain any fields, the program runs fine:

```
struct Command {};
...
```

AFAIK since Command is taken as a const reference, its lifetime should be extended to the end of main here, so it should not be a dangling reference to a temporary.

Moreover if I do not access count in the lambda the program does not segfault:

```
...
    int count{};
    AutoBrake brake{ [&count](const Command&) {} };
    brake.publish(Command{});
...
```

Finally, if I first store the lambda as a variable it does not segfault:

```
    int count{};
    auto func = [&count](const Command&) { count += 1; };
    AutoBrake brake{ func };
    brake.publish(Command{});
```

Comment: [some const reference still doesn't prolong the lifetime of a temporary today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784262/does-a-const-reference-class-member-prolong-the-life-of-a-temporary).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You store dangling lambda in `AutoBrake`.

You might do either:

```
template <typename T>
struct AutoBrake {
    AutoBrake(const T& publish) : publish{ publish } {}
    T publish;
};
```

or

```
int count{};
auto lambda = [&count](const Command&) {
        count += 1;
    };
AutoBrake brake{ lambda };
```

Your "working" variations are just possible outputs of Undefined Behaviour (UB).