# What happens in C++ if a function return value is passed to a function reference argument?

Tags: c++, performance, reference, return, copy

Let's consider two functions:

```
//Test functions
Object MakeObj(){/* processsing */};
Object ChangeObj(const Object& obj){/* processsing */};
//Then execute
Object test_obj = ChangeObj(MakeObj());
```

1. Is the execution safe?
2. Where is stored the 'Object' return value of the MakeObj()? Can I use a reference to that storage?
3. Or a temporary variable is necessary:

   ```
   Object MakeObj(){/* processsing */};
   Object ChangeObj(const Object& obj){/* processsing */};
   Object tmp_obj = MakeObj();
   Object test_obj = ChangeObj(tmp_obj);
   ```
4. Is there any performance gain or it is exactly the same, if the code from point 3 gets changed:

   ```
   Object MakeObj(){/* processsing */};
   Object ChangeObj(Object obj){/* processsing */}; //No reference here, so 'Object' value is created.
   Object test_obj = ChangeObj(MakeObj());
   ```
5. Is there a way to use "move" to avoid coping a big Object? E.g:

   ```
   Object ChangeObj(Object&& obj){/* processsing */};
   ```

   If yes, how it would look like?
6. What would be the fastest implementation (as less coping as possible) of those two functions above? Assumption: "Object MakeObj();" declaration cannot be changed.

Comment: `Object test_obj = ChangeObj(MakeObj());` doesn't compile, so you don't to worry about it.

Comment: `&&` isn't just a "move" reference, but also called a "generic" or even "rvalue" reference. It's called rvalue reference because you can use it for rvalues, like what `MakeObj()` returns.

Comment: When some object is returned from a function, it typically works such that the caller allocates storage for this object on its stack and then passes its address as a hidden argument to the called function. This function then may (or must) create the returned object directly in this storage. Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/KEhqvvKoW (address of the storage is passed in `rdi` to `f`). However, generally, this whole problem is much more complicated (for instance, small trivial objects are usually passed in registers).

Comment: what is `ChangeObject` doing? Why is it taking the parameter by non-const reference *and* returns an `Object` ?

Comment: The edit to make the argument a **`const`** reference changes quite a lot. I'd argue that change makes this a whole new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Execution is safe because [const reference extends object lifetime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2784304/10567061)(or [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime))
2. The object itself is stored somewhere on the stack, but it will not be erased as long as the const reference exists([compare](https://godbolt.org/z/MdnP9oPd6) asm line 20(non-reference) and 25-27(const reference))
3. No. It isn't necessary.
4. In the general case, the code from point 4 is faster, even if there was a `move` (in the case of a `vector`, optimization for 2-3 assignment operations `size_t`)
5. `move` can only be applied in the code from point 3, and then it will look like

```
Object MakeObj(){/* processsing */};
Object ChangeObj(Object&& obj){/* processsing */};
Object tmp_obj = MakeObj();
Object test_obj = ChangeObj(std::move(tmp_obj));
//here tmp_obj is no longer valid
```

6. Code from point 4 should be the fastest, but MEASURE!!! And remember about first rule of optimization: Don't optimize prematurely

Comment: I realized that the code from the introduction is the fastest, so faster than point 4 because it is one 'Object' variable creation less. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: But RVO should optimize that excesive object creation @JerzyJamroz